# $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac1{4^k(2k+1)}\binom{2k}{k}x^{2k+1}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k\frac1{4^k}\binom{2k}{k}x^k =$

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, binomial-coefficients, power-series, taylor-expansion

Prove that for $|x|<1$,

$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac1{4^k(2k+1)}\binom{2k}{k}x^{2k+1}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k\frac1{4^k}\binom{2k}{k}(-x^2)^k = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^{2k-1}}{k\binom{2k}{k}}x^{2k-1}$

Here's my round-about approach:

First show that

$\arcsin x = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac1{4^k(2k+1)}\binom{2k}{k}x^{2k+1}$

and then show that

$2\frac{\arcsin x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{2k}{k^2\binom{2k}{k}}2^{2k-1}x^{2k-1}$

using (by differentiating) $(\arcsin x)^2=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^{2k-1}x^{2k}}{k^2\binom{2k}{k}}$

(to show the last identity, consider $(1-x^2)y''-xy'-2=0$ with $y(0)=y'(0)=0$ by first solving directly using integrating factor and then solve it by using series.

Then use $1/\sqrt{1-x^2}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{-1/2}k(-x^2)^k=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k\frac1{4^k}\binom{2k}k(-x^2)^k$

Then by expressing $2\frac{\arcsin x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ in two different ways, we are done.

Any other approach is welcome.

Comment: Woah there. You should really use different indices for the two summations. That is really, really bad form.

Comment: @CameronWilliams What...?